# Rails form with remote: true reloads the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, forms

In my Rails 5.1 app i have 2 controllers: home_controller and posts_controller which i created with the scaffold tool, so what i'm doing is rendering the partial `_form.html.haml` in the index view of my `home_controller.rb`  like this: (by the way i'm using haml)

```
.top-space
.row.center-xs
    .col-xs-8.col-md-10
        .row
            .col-sm-3.col-lg-2.col-xs-10.top-space
                %ul.no-bullets.text-left
                    %li=link_to "Explore", "#"
                    %li=link_to "Suggestions", "#"
            .col-sm.col-xs-10
                =render "posts/form"
            #posts
```

i added `remote: true` to the form like this:

```
= form_for @post, remote: true do |f|
 - if @post.errors.any?
 #error_explanation
  %h2= "#{pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this post from being saved:"
  %ul
    - @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
      %li= message
 .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.full-width
   = f.text_area :body, class:"mdl-textfield__input", row:3
   = f.label :body, "Write something",class:"mdl-textfield__label"
.actions.text-right
= f.submit 'Save',class:"mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored"
```

as you can see it has `remote: true` but when i submit the form it takes me to the show view in my posts_controller,
this is my `posts_controller`:

```
def create
 @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
   respond_to do |format|
     if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post}
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
     else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

i created a `show.js.coffee` to show the post created in a `<div id="posts">` below the form

```
$('#posts').append('<%= j render @post %>')
```

Basically what i want is to show the post created below the form without reloading the page or taking me to show view in my `posts_controller`.

What am i doing wrong and how can i achieve this?

Comment: Check browser inspector (in chrome: ctrl+shift+j or F12) for JS errors, maybe your JS files are not loaded?

Comment: There are no errors, all the js files are being loaded

Comment: Do you have `resources :posts` in your `routes.rb` file? And is the `jquery-ujs` javascript file loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set your create action like this maybe:

```
def create
 @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
   respond_to do |format|
     if @post.save
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to @post}
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
     else
      format.js
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

i have just added format.js